# ExpandableListView - empty group message

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am developing an app which has an ExpandableListActivity. When a group has no children, I would like it to show a message, as if it was a child, informing that the list is empty, as shown in the picture:

[image: screen capture]

Is there any (reasonably simple) way to do this, or something similar?

I am sorry if this has been asked before - I kind of assume it must have been, but I haven't been able to find anything. Thank you!

EDIT: To clarify, what I'm looking for is not an empty view for the complete ExpandableListView (which can be set with setEmptyView), but for parent groups with no children.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My experience with this particular class isn't that great, but I would suggest trying to override the Adapter's `getChildrenCount` method to return 1 when there aren't any child records.

Then, in the Adapter's `getChildView` method, if you cannot find any child for the specified parent, return a custom view containing your message.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan! That sounds quite reasonable, I'll try my luck and I'll let you know how it went :)

Comment: Welp - yeah, sort of. Deadline came, so I couldn't quite get it working, but I tried it for a while and this definitely seemed like the way to go. I'm accepting it as answer, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

correct me if i am wrong but you can use method setEmpty() to inform a list to be empty. 
Assuming you have a custom expandable list view in xml with id of android:list and another text view with id of android:empty. In code, you just need to have list.setEmpty(empty_text_view);

Comment: Hello, Jacky! Thank you for your suggestion, and that works - but for setting an empty view for the whole expandablelist (i.e. no groups), while what I'm looking for is an empty view for each group (that is, there is a parent group with no children). I'm going to clarify that in the question anyway, thank you for your time!