# Alternate view for an empty group in an expandableList

Tags: android, expandablelistview

The question is simple, but I can't make it work.
I have a expandable list with 3 header, they can be either populated or empty.

I wish to show a simple textview when you expand a group that is empty, I've been looking for a while but nothing seems to work.
i can't use setEmpty() because this will only work if all the groups are empty.

I found a similar thread here: [ExpandableListView - empty group message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667707/expandablelistview-empty-group-message)

If i try to do as the accepted answer suggested, so:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if(this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size() != 0){
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();        
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I get an error when i try to expand the empty group ... And I don't think this would work anyway, for instance what will happen if I have a group with 1 child, will it be considerated as empty ??

EDIT:

Ok I solved this by always having an null object at the first place in mys child list, then when getchildrencount returns 1, I know it's actually empty and so I call the empty case of the switch.
In the populated case of the switch i always hide the first element, this might not be the cleanest way to do this, but this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using different layouts whether they are populated or empty, you can distinguish by overriding `getChildType` or `getGroupType` like this

```
private static final int CHILD_TYPE_COUNT = 2;

@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    if(obj.isEmpty())
        return 0;
    else if(obj.isPopulated)
        return 1;
}

@Override
public int getChildTypeCount() {
    return CHILD_TYPE_COUNT;
}
```

Then you can use the corresponding layout to populate. I suggest you also use the [ViewHolder-Pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

```
static class PopulatedViewHolder {
    //declare the elements of a populated view here
}

static class EmptyViewHolder {
    //declare the elements of an empty view here
}


@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    EmptyViewHolder emptyViewHolder = null;
    PopulatedViewHolder populatedViewHolder = null;

    //check if the type of your view is populated or empty and use the corresponding layout
    int type = getChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null || (type == 0 && (convertView.getTag()) instanceof PopulatedViewHolder) || (type == 1 && (convertView.getTag()) instanceof EmptyViewHolder)) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        switch(type){
            case 0:
                //type is empty
                emptyViewHolder =  new EmptyViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_layout,
                        parent, false);

                //...initialize your viewcomponents of the populated layout here...

                convertView.setTag(emptyViewHolder);
                break;
            case 1:
                //populated
                populatedViewHolder = new PopulatedViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.populated_layout, parent, false);

                //...initialize your viewcomponents of the populated layout here...

                convertView.setTag(populatedViewHolder);

                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                emptyViewHolder = (EmptyViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                break;

            case 1:
                PopulatedViewHolder = (PopulatedViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                break;
        }
    }

    switch(type){
        case 0:
            //empty
            //set the values of your empty view here

            break;
        case 1:
            //populated
            //set the values of your populated view here

            break;
     }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I understand your code and I also think this should works but for some reasons, it's not...
The app works, when a populated groups is expanded it's working fine, but when I try to expand an empty group (using your code) it's still doesn't do anything, I can see the group is expanding because I have an indicator but the textview that is supposed to show up for empty group doesn't show up..
this is my adapter: http://pastebin.com/Yvq5Aveq

my 2 layout (list_item and empty_layout are bassicaly the same, 2 linear layout with just a textview)

Comment: have you debugged the code to see if the debugger steps in the correct switch-cases?

Comment: You're right, even in an empty group, it goes in the populated switch case

Comment: Are you using instances of `PopulatedViewHolder` and `EmptyViewHolder`? Otherwise, `if (convertView == null || (type == 0 && (convertView.getTag()) instanceof PopulatedViewHolder)
                                                        || (type == 1 && (convertView.getTag()) instanceof EmptyViewHolder))` will only be true for the first time (when the convertView is null)

Comment: When I expand/collapse the empty group getChildType() is never called, it is called though for the populated groups

Comment: Yes I do use PopulatedViewHolder and EmptyViewHolder

Comment: after some debugging, I noticed some really weird stuff, if a click on an empty group, this will never call getchilltype for some reason..
And also, I tired to do something like
 int type = getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
So it would retur me 0 in case of there are no child BUT and I can't explain this, getChildrenCount is indeed called and the value inside is correct (0) but it seems like getchildview isn't even called...

Answer (score 0):

if you are extending BaseExpandableListAdapter, you can change your getGroupView of BaseExpandableListAdapter to return different views for different positions depending on whether their children are empty or not

public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
// empty data for second child and getting view for second position
if(position == 1 && _childData.getCount(1) == 0) 
{
// return new TextView, you could create a member variable textview, and return that
}
}

Comment: I do extend BaseExpandableListAdapter, could you provide an example ?